# Copying updated files from one server to another after 15 min

Tags: linux, shell, expect, rsync, scp

I want to copy updated file from one server to another every 15 min when the new file gets generated. I have written code using expect script. It works fine but after 15 min it copies all the files in the directory i.e. it replaces and copy latest one also. I want only updated file (updated every 15 min) to get copied and not all the files.

Here is my script:

```
while :
do
        expect -c "spawn scp -P $Port sftpuser@$IP_APP:/mnt/oam/PmCounters/LBO* Test/;expect \"password\";send \"password\r\";expect eof"
        sleep 900
done
```

can I use rsync or any other approach and how?

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` does only copy changed or new file by default. Use for example that syntax:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /local/dir/
```

That specifies ssh as remote shell to use (`-e ssh ...`), `-a` activates archive mode, `-v` sets verbose output and `-z` compresses the transfer.

You could run that every 15 minutes by a cronjob.

For the password you can use the `$RSYNC_PASSWORD` environment variable or the `--password-file` flag.